# Let $X\subseteq \mathbb R_{>0}$ be uncountable. Prove there is a countable subset $S$ of$ X$, such that $\sum_{x\in S} x=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

In other words:
Suppose that there is uncountable subset $X$ of the positive Real numers.
Prove that there is countable subset $S$ of $X$ that the sum of elements in $S$  is infinite.

The only thing I thought about was the Natural number but they don't have to be a subset of $X$ if $X$ is only real number without natural number.

Comment: This is very hard to read.

Comment: I tried to write it in words that's better?

Comment: Sums have organs?  Hint:  consider the buckets $[1,\infty), [\frac 12, 1), [\frac 13, \frac 12), \cdots$.  One of these must contain infinitely many of your set.

Comment: the sum of all the x1,x2,...,xn in the countable subset of X

Comment: Yes.  Is my hint clear?

Comment: No, I don't understand the context to my question

Comment: You have a set of positive numbers.  Each of those numbers has to be in exactly one of my buckets.  If there were only finitely many of your elements in each bucket then there would be finite or countably many elements in your set (why?).  It follows that at least one of my buckets has infinitely many of your elements and that gives you your set $S$ (why?)

Answer (score 2):

For $n \in \Bbb N$, consider the sets $A_n := [\frac 1 n , \frac 1 {n-1})$, with $\frac 1 0 := \infty$.
Then suppose $A_n \cap X$ is finite for every $n\in\Bbb N$. Observe that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n = \Bbb R _{>0}$. So,
$$X = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\cap X$$
would be an countable set as countable union of finite sets. Contradiction.
Thus there exists an $m\in \Bbb N$ such that $A_m\cap X$ is infinite. Now take some infinite countable subset $S$ of $A_m\cap X$, for example take successively different elements of $A_m\cap X$. Obviously $S\subseteq X$, and since for every $s\in S $ holds  $s > \frac 1 m > 0$
$$\sum_{s\in S} s \geq \sum_{s\in S} \frac 1 m = \infty$$

Comment: Close, but your specific construction fails.  $A_m\cap X\cap \mathbb Q$ could certainly be empty  (suppose $X$ is the set of positive irrationals).

Comment: Ah, of course you are right. Then we have to choose elements of $A_m \cap X$ successively. Thank god, we have the axiom of choice :)

Comment: Exactly so.  (+1)